# "bbcode" script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

This is a jQuery variant of a script (it doesn't work):

```
<script language="javascript">
$("div.post-content").each(function(){
    if($(this).innerHTML.indexOf("[/float]") != -1) {
        pattern= /\[float=(.*?)\]([^\[]*)\[\/float\]/gi
        $(this).html($(this).innerHTML.replace(pattern, "<span style='float: $1;'>$2</span>"))
    }
})
</script>
```

This is the pure Javascript variant (it works perfectly):

```
<script language="javascript">
posts=document.getElementsByTagName("div")
for(x in posts) if(posts[x].className=="post-content") {
    post = posts[x].innerHTML;
    if(post.indexOf("[/float]") != -1) {
        pattern = /\[float=(.*?)\]([^\[]*)\[\/float\]/gi
        posts[x].innerHTML = posts[x].innerHTML.replace(pattern, "<span style='float: $1;'>$2</span>")
    }
}
</script>
```

What this script does:

1. It seeks out all divs with class `post-content`.
2. It checks whether there's a closing tag for bbcode.
3. By using regular expression, it seeks out patterns of given bbcode tags.
4. It replaces bbcode tags with html element.

I don't know what I did wrong here...

Comment: Start by replacing `innterHTML` with `innerHTML`

Comment: awww, crap. Dat typo. Still not working tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `innerHTML` when using jQuery. It's wrong when assigning a value (memory leaks), and a bad practice when reading a value. Use

```
$(this).html()
```

or, if you really want to,

```
$(this)[0].innerHTML
```

The jQuery object returns an *array*, that doesn't have a `innerHTML` property. But then again, use `.html()` for a code more of the style of jQuery.

Comment: A third variant is to replace `$(this).innerHTML` with `$(this).get(0).innerHTML`.

Comment: @scessor Yes, I've forgot about that because I've never seen the point of it, so never used it. It's just a slower function call when you can directly access the element in the array.